# webpack compiled with 27 errors and 3 warnings

Tags: webpack

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 72:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/on-finished/index.js 191:11-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\on-finished'

WARNING in ./node_modules/raw-body/index.js 270:11-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\raw-body'

ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js 201:12-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
- install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 21:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 15:17-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\destroy'

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 17:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 21:12-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\etag'

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 22:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 29:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 17:11-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 20:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 23:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 23:18-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
- install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 16:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 17:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\express\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 1:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\mime'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\mime'

ERROR in ./node_modules/parseurl/index.js 14:10-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\parseurl'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/safer-buffer/safer.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\safer-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 22:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\send'

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 27:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 18:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js 20:10-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'H:\Shekhar\react programs\myProject\coder roadmap (V4)\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

webpack compiled with 27 errors and 3 warnings

Please Solve my error

server can be successfully running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install another version of webpack:
`npm install webpack@5.88.2`